# How to create a responsive grid with squares?

Tags: mobile, grid, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently creating a grid, filled with buttons. Now I want this grid to be responsive and the buttons to be square-shaped. The thing I want to create will look like an iOS or Android homescreen (just buttons).

```cs
Grid grid = new Grid
        {

            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            RowSpacing = 15,
            ColumnSpacing = 15,
            ColumnDefinitions = 
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            MonitorButton button = new MonitorButton();
            grid.Children.Add(button, i % 3, i / 3);
        }

        this.Content = new ScrollView
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(15),
            Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
            Content = grid
        };
```

So right here I'm creating a grid with 3 columns, filled with 12 MonitorButtons (buttons with an image on the background). That looks alright.. Now when I'm opening the screen in landscape mode, the screen gets filled with rectangles, because the number of columns is still the same...
How can I solve this? I would like to have some kind of dynamic possibility (for example: itemscontrol @ XAML).

Comment: There is currently no GridView in Xamarin.Forms. you will have to calculate your column width (and spacing) and dynamically add your column definitions. This will be done using the [modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) `%`

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate your screen current page resizes itself, so it calls OnSizeRequest method in your page. If you override that method, you can detect both size and orientation.

**YourPage.cs || YourPage.xaml.cs**

```
protected override SizeRequest OnSizeRequest(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
{
    if(widthConstraint>heightConstraint)
    {
        //landscape mode
        //set your grid row & columndefinitions
    }
    else
    {
        //portait mode
        //set your grid row & columndefinitions
    }
    return base.OnSizeRequest(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this customised (Custom Grid Control) grid will be better to use, which have command so you can recognize which item is tapped, hence I think you may not need so many buttons on your UI also. 
and you can add whatever controls you want inside grid cell (in Square like you have added buttons)

GridView.Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.Controls.GridView">

</Grid>
```

GridView.Xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Test.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Test.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class GridView : Grid
    {
        public GridView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (var i = 0; i < MaxColumns; i++)
                ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create<GridView, object>(p => p.CommandParameter, null);
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<GridView, ICommand>(p => p.Command, null);
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create<GridView, IEnumerable<object>>(p => p.ItemsSource, null, BindingMode.OneWay, null, (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => { ((GridView)bindable).BuildTiles(newValue); });

        private int _maxColumns = 2;
        private float _tileHeight = 0;

        public Type ItemTemplate { get; set; } = typeof(SubControlsView);

        public int MaxColumns
        {
            get { return _maxColumns; }
            set { _maxColumns = value; }
        }

        public float TileHeight
        {
            get { return _tileHeight; }
            set { _tileHeight = value; }
        }

        public object CommandParameter
        {
            get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
        }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public void BuildTiles(IEnumerable<object> tiles)
        {
            try
            {
                if (tiles == null || tiles.Count() == 0)
                    Children?.Clear();

                // Wipe out the previous row definitions if they're there.
                RowDefinitions?.Clear();

                var enumerable = tiles as IList ?? tiles.ToList();
                var numberOfRows = Math.Ceiling(enumerable.Count / (float)MaxColumns);

                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
                    RowDefinitions?.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = TileHeight });

                for (var index = 0; index < enumerable.Count; index++)
                {
                    var column = index % MaxColumns;
                    var row = (int)Math.Floor(index / (float)MaxColumns);

                    var tile = BuildTile(enumerable[index]);

                    Children?.Add(tile, column, row);
                }
            }
            catch
            { // can throw exceptions if binding upon disposal
            }
        }

        private Layout BuildTile(object item1)
        {
            var buildTile = (Layout)Activator.CreateInstance(ItemTemplate, item1);
            buildTile.InputTransparent = false;

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = Command,
                CommandParameter = item1,
                NumberOfTapsRequired = 1
            };

            buildTile?.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);


            return buildTile;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can create your internal UI (View). i.e. the internal view of each grid square. In this example I have added only one label.

SubControlsView.Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.Views.SubControlsView" BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <!--You can add any controls which you want--> 
        <!--<Label Text="{Binding id}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" />-->

    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

SubControlsView.Xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Test.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SubControlsView : Grid
    {
        public SubControlsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public SubControlsView(object item)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Then using this controls wherever you want. i.e. On any content page. This will be your actual view (Dashboard)

SubCarriers.Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"
            x:Class="Test.Views.SubCarriers" Title="Details Dashboard">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView Margin="5">
            <control:GridView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        RowSpacing="5"
                        ColumnSpacing="5"
                        MaxColumns="2"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding SubCarriersCnt}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SubCarriersCnt}"
                        Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                        IsClippedToBounds="False">
                <control:GridView.TileHeight>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single"
                      iOS="60"
                      Android="90"
                      WinPhone="90" />
                </control:GridView.TileHeight>
            </control:GridView>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Then bind your ViewModel to your view. and implement ClickCommand in YourViewModel

SubCarriers.Xaml.cs

```
using System;
using Test.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using CommonUtility;

namespace Test.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SubCarriers : ContentPage
    {
        private YourViewModel viewModel;

        public SubCarriers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new SubCarriersViewModel();
            viewModel = (YourViewModel)this.BindingContext;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have implemented everything and it works except for the ClickCommand. I have tried several things but unable to get the click action. Please share the code if you can.